# PHP - preg_replace for /[[:punct:]]/ isn't removing double quotes

Tags: php

I'm trying to strip punctuation in the following string `"Peter !!!!!!!! MacIntyre"` (including the quotes at the end of the string). I'm using this code:

```
$filterItem = filter_var($searchTearm, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$duplicatePunctuation = preg_replace('/[[:punct:]]/', ' ', strval($filterItem));
$output = $duplicatePunctuation;
```

The output I'm getting is `34 Peter          MacIntyre  34`. The exclamation marks are replaced as it should be. However, the double quotes are being converted into the number 34. I tried str_replace but it wouldn't remove them.

I also tried `$duplicatePunctuation = str_replace(chr(34), ' ', strval($filterItem));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by using

```
$removeDoubleQuotes = trim(html_entity_decode($filterItem), '"');
```

Answer (score 1):

FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING: it Strip tags and HTML-encode double and single quotes, optionally strip or encode special characters. Encoding quotes can be disabled by setting FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES.[Document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

```
<?php
$searchTearm = '"Peter !!!!!!!! MacIntyre"';
$filterItem = filter_var($searchTearm,  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,  FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
$duplicatePunctuation = preg_replace('/[[:punct:]]/', ' ', $searchTearm);
$output = $duplicatePunctuation;

var_dump($output);
```